# detach disk from vm azure c#

Tags: c#, azure

the point is, i have to detach a disk in azure, using c# and the resourcemanager provided by azure.

atm i have following...

```
  var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId };
  var ObjVirtualMachines = computeClient.VirtualMachines.GetAsync(ressgroup, virtualmname, null, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
  var disk = new DataDisk(ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count,
  DiskCreateOptionTypes.Empty,
  name,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  new ManagedDiskParametersInner(resourceid, acctype));
  var newUpdateVM = computeClient.VirtualMachines.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ressgroup, virtualmname, ObjVirtualMachines);
```

I didn't get it. Its primary used to attach a disk, with different parameters. There is no deattach function, so i tried, setting it to Empty. But that wont work either.

I also experimented with the disk itself. But i have to detach the disk from it, so working on the disk alone will not reach to the goal.

Any Ideas how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, got a Solution that works...

```
   var ObjVirtualMachines = computeClient.VirtualMachines.GetAsync(ressgroup, virtualmname, null, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
   var disktodetach = ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
   ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Remove(disktodetach);
   var newUpdateVM = computeClient.VirtualMachines.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ressgroup, virtualmname, ObjVirtualMachines).Result;
```

Comment: Don't know if you know it, but you can mark your own answer as accepted, if it's the right one. It helps others to see that the question has a solution already.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to wait a little bit to see if no other answer comes! I was just making sure that you already knew it. ;-)

Comment: It's usually recommended that you `await` Async methods rather than hitting `.Result` (https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) - is there a reason you're doing it that way?

Comment: sure, we have a own automation software, wich have problems with the await. Results works better here, but you are right, await is the better option there